# how to clear the conflict in sql while retrieving the order by ratings?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am working on  php with sql and jquery actually i have two tables in database one is videos another one is teachers rating suppose if teacher give the rating to videos i want to show order by rating if one teacher give the rating its working if multiple teachers give the rating to same video it's conflicting and its not showing order by rating. please give the answer thank you.

**my sql query is:**

```
<?php
    $search=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_SESSION['search']));  
    if($search!='')
    {
        $query="SELECT v.id,v.youtube_video_id,v.title,v.description FROM 
                videos v left join teachers_rating tr on 
                tr.video_id=v.youtube_video_id where v.title LIKE 
                '%".$search."%'  or v.description like '%".$search."%'GROUP 
                BY v.youtube_video_id  order by AVG(tr.rating) desc  limit 10";
    }
    else {
        $query="SELECT v.id,v.youtube_video_id,v.title,v.description FROM 
                videos v left join teachers_rating tr on 
                tr.video_id=v.youtube_video_id where 
                v.keyword_id='".$_SESSION['topic_id']."'GROUP BY 
                v.youtube_video_id  order by AVG(tr.rating) desc limit 10";
    }
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$videosarray=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$inarray='';
$inarrayvideos='';
$videos=array();
if(count($videosarray)){
    foreach($videosarray as $key=>$video)
    {
        $videos[$key]['youtube_video_id']=$video['youtube_video_id'];
        $videos[$key]['description']=$video['description'];
        $videos[$key]['title']=$video['title'];
        $inarray.='"'.$video['youtube_video_id'].'",';
    }
    $inarrayvideos=trim($inarray, ",");
}
```

Comment: Can you add your DB? Not clear what's `videos` & `teachers_rating` fields

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `youtube_video_id` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=268 ;

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teachers_rating` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `teacher_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `video_id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_relevent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;